# USB ports at 10Volt

Tags: drivers, usb, power-management

There is a small "driver" from asus, [AI Charger](http://event.asus.com/mb/2010/ai_charger/), that turns the PC's USB ports into 10V power supplier, which allows me to charge my iPad from my computer. Problem is, this only works on windows. Is there any way to do the same on Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this page http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-charge-ipad-on-ubuntu-linux-via-usb-ports

Make sure you read the whole page including comments.

If you have an iPad2 you will need to change the product ID before compiling.

I used these instructions now I just need to run ipad-charge in a terminal when I connect my iPad2.

Hope this helps.